# Tar files created in last 15 minutes and SCP them to my local machine. (Using Cygwin)

Tags: linux, scripting, cygwin, redhat

I am trying to create a `shell script` to make `tar` out of a selected list of files with filename starting with *AppLog* , created within last 15 minutes on a remote server. The `tar` is then supposed to `scp` the files to my local machine.

My current problem is that the `find` option fetches files and lists it, but when the `tar` is created only the recent 1 file is zipped even though there might be more than 1 item in the `find` output. Please review my script below and advise.

Please note, I am using Cygwin to run this script on Win7.

```
#!/bin/bash
Systime=`date +%F-%H%M%S`
sshpass -p xxxxxx ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd /path/to/dir/with/logs && find AppLog* -cmin -15 -type f -exec tar -zcvf /dest/sys01-$Systime.tar.gz {} \;"
sshpass -p xxxxxx scp root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/dest/sys01-$Systime.tar.gz . 
sshpass -p xxxxxx ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "rm -rf /dest/sys01-$Systime.tar.gz"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find command is executing tar for every files found. So you are overwriting  the tar file every time for this reason only the last file is present.

You need to execute the tar with the full list, only one time.

```
cd /path/to/dir/with/logs && find AppLog* -cmin -15 -type f | xargs tar -zcvf /dest/sys01-$Systime.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! finally. Got it.

```
sshpass -p xxxxxx ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd /path/to/dir/with/logs && find . -name 'Applog*.log' -cmin -15 -print | xargs tar cvf /dest/Applog-$Systime.tar.gz
```